Room Database: Cursor Conversion Errors in WorkoutDao for Queries and Insertions with Kotlin Coroutines - Help Needed to Resolve
I'm developing a fitness app using Android Studio with Room as the database. I'm encountering issues with Room's queries and insertions in my WorkoutDao. Specifically, I'm seeing errors related to handling cursors and continuations. Despite following Room documentation and several guides, I can't seem to resolve these issues.
Error Messages:
Error: "Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object)"
Occurs at the following queries:
getExercisesForWorkout
getSetsForExercise
Error: "Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it."
Unused parameter: $completion in queries.
package com.example.teampotentialfitness

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface WorkoutDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWorkout(workout: Workout): Long

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertExercise(exercise: Exercise): Long

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertSet(set: Set): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM exercise_table WHERE workoutId = :workoutId")
    fun getExercisesForWorkout(workoutId: Int): Flow<List<Exercise>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM set_table WHERE exerciseId = :exerciseId")
    fun getSetsForExercise(exerciseId: Int): Flow<List<Set>>
}


package com.example.teampotentialfitness

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [Exercise::class, Workout::class, Set::class], version = 1)
abstract class WorkoutDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun workoutDao(): WorkoutDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: WorkoutDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): WorkoutDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    WorkoutDatabase::class.java,
                    "workout_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}


package com.example.teampotentialfitness

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "exercise_table")
data class Exercise(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    val name: String,
    val workoutId: Int
)


package com.example.teampotentialfitness

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "workout_table")
data class Workout(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    val workoutName: String
)


package com.example.teampotentialfitness

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "set_table")
data class Set(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,

    val reps: Int,
    val weight: Float,
    val exerciseId: Int
)


package com.example.teampotentialfitness

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.teampotentialfitness.ui.theme.TeamPotentialFitnessTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            TeamPotentialFitnessTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(name = "Team Potential Fitness", modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(text = "Welcome to $name!", modifier = modifier)
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    TeamPotentialFitnessTheme {
        Greeting("Team Potential Fitness")
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.teampotentialfitness"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.5.1"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.5.0"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.5.0"
}


**I've tried several solutions like changing the method signatures, tweaking database queries, and adjusting build configurations, but the issue persists.
Has anyone encountered similar problems or can suggest a solution to resolve these Room database issues?
Thanks in advance!**
I've been developing a fitness app using Kotlin and Android Studio, integrating Room Database to manage Workout, Exercise, and Set entities. The issue arises when running Room queries or insert operations via Kotlin coroutines in the WorkoutDao class. Specifically, I receive "Not sure how to convert a Cursor" and "Unused parameter" errors when querying the database or trying to insert data.
I expected the queries and insertions to work smoothly, given that I'm following Room and Kotlin coroutine best practices, but these errors persist. I have tried:
Correcting data types in the queries and inserts.
Verifying that the entities are properly annotated.
Ensuring the correct use of coroutines with suspend functions in WorkoutDao.
Running fallbackToDestructiveMigration() in the database builder.
Checking if the WorkoutDao return types are causing issues with how the database reads and converts data.
Despite these attempts, the errors continue. Below is the relevant code for reference.

I believe the error is due to the name Set! Try changing this class name to something else as there is an in-built data type in Kotlin named Set which might be conflicting with your entity's name. Let, me know the result and I'll post this as an answer.

The error is self-explanatory.
This error is due to the entity name Set! Change your entity class name to something else as there is an in-built datatype in Kotlin named Set which is conflicting with your entity's name.
